# C — Why «write» can't write in file?

Tags: c, file, file-io, system-calls, file-descriptor

I want to deal with `write`: why doesn't it write to a file (errno 9, `EBADF: Bad file descriptor`), although if you replace `fdOut` with `1`, then everything is perfectly displayed on the screen?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main (void)
{
    int     fdOut;
    char    *outFileName = "out";
    char    sample[7] ="sample\0";
    
    fdOut = open (outFileName, O_CREAT, 0777);
    if (fdOut == -1)
        printf ("ups, errno %d\n", errno);
    else
    {
            write (fdOut, sample, 7);
            write (fdOut, "\n", 1);
    }
    close (fdOut);
    printf ("%s", sample);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `close` should only happen when the file was actually opened (i.e. in the `else` block, not after)

Comment: You also probably want to add `O_WRONLY`.

Comment: you can also use `fopen()` which is `open` specific for files (and then `fwrite()` and `fclose()`)

Comment: File numbers 0 is standard input,1 is standard output, 2 is standard error output : these files are opened at start of program.

Comment: If you read "man write" you read that "EBADF" means "fd is not a valid file descriptor or is not open for writing". So now you know you maybe didn't open the file properly for writing. And there you read "The argument flags must include one of the following access modes: O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR. These request opening the file read-only, write-only, or read/write, respectively." So it's really about reading the errors, then reading the documentation.

Comment: gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled.c" -o "untitled.o" 
untitled.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled.c:16:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘write’; did you mean ‘fwrite’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   16 |             write (fdOut, sample, 7);
      |             ^~~~~
      |             fwrite
untitled.c:19:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘close’; did you mean ‘pclose’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   19 |     close (fdOut);
      |     ^~~~~
      |     pclose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of `open` (e.g. [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)), we see:

> The argument *flags* must include one of the following *access modes*: `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, or `O_RDWR`.  These request opening the file read-only, write-only, or read/write, respectively.

It's safe to assume that you want `O_WRONLY` in this case:

```
fdOut = open (outFileName, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0777);
```

You may also want to look into `O_TRUNC` for cases where the file does exist.

Comment: For the record, on Linux, `O_RDONLY` has numeric value `0`.  So `open(name, O_CREAT, 0777)` is actually `open(name, O_CREAT|O_RDONLY, 0777)`, because neither of the bits for `O_WRONLY` (1) or `O_RDWR` (2) were set.  `strace ./a.out` will decode accordingly; it's a very useful tool that decodes args and return values for system calls.

Comment: @PeterCordes. Relying on the value of a macro makes a really unportable code, potentially even between versions of the same OS.

Comment: I point this out as a way to understand actual behaviour of buggy code, not as a suggestion for writing code that way!  For example, that's why Linux `open()` can't detect the error of not specifying a read/write mode and return `-EINVAL` as documented for "invalid value in `flags`", because it's actually not invalid.  And also as a fun peek behind the curtain at a non-obvious design decision that went into choosing these flags values, and what `strace` (and the kernel) have to do to infer `O_RDONLY` from the low 2 bits both being clear.

Comment: IDK why they didn't just pick bit 0 = read or not, bit 1 = write or not, so O_RDWR could be 3, both set, and neither set would be invalid.  In the actual design Linux picked, the only error they can detect in the access-mode bits is `O_WRONLY|O_RDWR`.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's not an error on Linux.  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html#NOTES "Linux reserves the special, nonstandard access mode 3 (binary 11) in `flags` to mean: check for read and write permission on the file and return a file descriptor that can't be used for reading or writing.  This nonstandard access mode is used by some Linux drivers to return a file descriptor that is to be used only for device-specific `ioctl(2)` operations."  FWIW, the values of `O_RDONLY` *et al* date back to the very first Unix versions. `sys/fcntl.h` on Solaris 11.4 has "© 1984 AT&T" in it.