# Write to a file with the write syscall in GNU assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, gnu-assembler

```
.global _start
.intel_syntax noprefix

.text
_start:
    /*
    This is writing a file in ASM
    */
    mov rax, 2              // open opcode
    lea rdi, [rip+file]     // const *
    mov rsi, 0100           // O_CREAT
    mov rdx, 0700           // RWX mode 
    syscall

    mov rdi, rax            // copy the fd rax as the last syscall returned that
    lea rsi, [rip+message]  // message pointer
    mov rdx, 13             // message length
    mov rax, 1              // write opcode
    syscall

    /*
        This is exiting in ASM
    */
    mov rax, 60 // exit opcode
    mov rdi, 0  // exit with 0
    syscall

.data
message:
    .ascii "Hello sailor\n" // normal string

file:
    .asciz "main" // null terminated string
```

Creating the file with open works as intended.

I am trying to write to the file I am creating here. As you can see I am passing the correct opcode and pointer to the buffer and also the length.

I am expecting the message to be in the file when I cat it but it is empty right now.

One other note is that when I change the file descriptor to 1 or 2 when writing it works as expected printing to the terminal so i am pretty sure the string is not the issue.

Comment: What does `strace ./a.out` say?  It should show you an error return from the `write()` system call if there is one.  e.g. `-EBADF` from a read-only file descriptor from 
 `open(O_CREAT|O_RDONLY)` (`O_RDONLY` is 0, so the default).  The file permissions if the file gets created are unrelated to the mode you open with.

Comment: `write(3, "Hello sailor\n", 13)  = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)`

Comment: But in the line before it says open returned 3 as the file descriptor. `open("main", O_RDONLY|O_CREAT, 0700)    = 3`

Comment: Yup, there you go.  Since the `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR` bits weren't set in the open flags, `strace` helpfully added `O_RDONLY` to show you the meaning of the args you passed.  `O_RDONLY` has numeric value `0`, so strace has to be smart about this to not make it part of any flags value that has one of the other bits set.  In the C man page, it tells you the `flags` *must include one of the following access modes: O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR"*  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Comment: Agh okay, how can I and two numbers in asm with the O_CREAT for the flags field

Comment: `mov esi, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY`.  The assembler can do assemble-time math in expressions involving `|` (you want OR not AND) or other operators, if it has definitions. 
 (After extracting definitions numeric from C headers for use with asm, as shown in [Opening file modes in x86 assembly Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71558966) .)  To do it manually, `O_WRONLY` is `1`, so `mov esi, 0100 | 0001`, or equivalently `mov esi, 0101` to do the bitwise OR yourself.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [How to read from and write to files using NASM for x86-64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20133698) which mentions the need for `O_WRONLY` but isn't specifically about that.  Oh, [C — Why «write» can't write in file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69619092) is a C duplicate about system call args, with exactly the bug you have.

Answer (score -1):

Using `strace ./a.out` you can see `open("main", O_RDONLY|O_CREAT, 0700) = 3`.

This means I was opening the file in read only mode. To not do this I change the line to `mov rsi, 0100|02` which now means I am opening it in read and write mode.